# how to use Wildcards in koa-route

Tags: node.js, routes, koa

```
var path = require('path')
var route= require('koa-route');//路由
app.use(route.get('/api/*',api.before));
```

I can't use it for this,how should I use wildcards in koa-route? Or,which other can do ?

---

Comment: I want to complete this. when I go to '/api/test' ,the route can first go to '/api/*',then goto '/api/test',how should I do ?

Answer (score 4):

I've been using https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router. I found `koa-route` too limiting.

It allows RegExp matching:

```
app.use(require('koa-router')(app));

// Matches '/test', '/test/foo/bar', '/test/foo/bar?page=2'
// but does NOT match '/test-route'
app.get(/^\/test(?:\/|$)/, function*() {
  this.body = 'Test';
});
```

It looks to me like you're trying to attach middleware on `/api/*` that will run before all `/api/*` routes (like for authentication). This is how you can do that with koa-router:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// File: routes/api.js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var Router = require('koa-router');

// Create a router instance to bind middleware/routes to.
// Our module will export it so that our main routes.js file can
// mount it to our app.
var router = new Router();

// Middleware that ensures that a user is logged in for
// all routes attached to this router.
router.use(function*(next) {
  this.assert(this.currentUser, 403);
  yield next;
});

router.get('/test', function*() {
  this.body = 'You went to /api/test';
});

module.exports = router;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// File: routes.js
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var app = require('koa')();
var mount = require('koa-mount');

var apiRouter = require('./routes/api');
app.use(mount('/api', apiRouter.routes()));
```

If you navigate to `/api`, it'll be handled by the `/` handler in the router since you mounted it to `/api`, and it will return 403 unless you are logged in.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I want to complete this.  when I go to '/api/test' ,the route can first go to '/api/*',then goto '/api/test',how should I do ?

Comment: @user3883185 Updated the code. GET /api/test will first hit the middleware and then go to the /test handler if the middleware succeeds.

Comment: +1 Excellent example, I've been looking for this type of example everywhere, you should do a tutorial on auth process as one is missing!

Answer (score 0):

For

```
app.use(route.get('/api/*',api.before));
```

In api.before:

```
/api/a/b/c 
==> 
ctx.params[0] ;  // => a/b/c
```